# High gate pin current leakage on a P-channel MOSFET

Tags: power-supply, mosfet

I have added a P-MOSFET before my main circuit, between the V+ of the battery, and the Vcc main power line of the circuit, so that the battery stays disconnected and doesn't drain until I am ready to use it.

The gate is connected to the source of the MOSFET with a 470 kΩ resistor. I would expect the Vgs to be 0 V until I pull it down with an extra transistor and an 'on' signal. However, without doing anything, Vgs seems to settle at -0.3 V.

[image: circuit]

Here is the circuit. Any idea what is causing the leakage? Or is it a high-frequency on/off oscillation? And how do I fix it?

Comment: It might help if you measure all DC voltages in the PMOS = off situation and add the values of those voltages to your drawing. My suspicion is that Q35 shows leakage.

Comment: The Mosfet you show in your schematic is a N-channel mosfet, not a P-channel one. And, its Enhancement type (again, that is what the schematic shows), which means it turns on when Vgs is positive, and turns off when Vgs is 0. Here is its datasheet: https://www.tme.eu/Document/e00b1812d1718dfbcc14ba33edf0c8e0/YJL3400A.pdf
Check again, its a P-channel as you say it is?

Comment: You draw n-channel MOSFET but in text p-channel.

Comment: D8 and 9 look like they might have leakage. Choose a small signal diode.

Comment: the n-channel mosfet is the transistor that pulls down the gate of the p-channel mosfet.  the p-channel mosfet is the 8 pin chip (dmp2022)

Comment: thanks bimpelrekkie for an answer to try out.  I disconnected the n-channel mosfet to try again.  unfortunately, I still get a 0.3v drop...  I did also try with a smaller 100k resistor, and get only a 0.05v drop.

Comment: the voltage drop and continuous drain is an issue that I don't understand, but I guess it only drains .025uW with the 100k resistor.  so that is not too bad.  But the p-mosfet seems to also allow an initial inrush through that latches the Vcc automatically  (Normally an initial 'on' pulse is fed through D9, and then Vcc is fed back through D8 to keep it on)
I think the issues may be connected (perhaps it is oscillating on / off slightly?)
Any thoughts on how to bias it off more robustly?  or add some impedance to the Vcc feedback signal so small inrush pulses don't latch?

Comment: Kartman - I will also research small signal diodes.  not so familiar with the differences in the diodes.  But wouldn't a bigger, slower reacting diode be better here to keep the n channel mosfet off until a stronger robust 'power on' signal is given?

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that Q35 shows leakage. Let's look in the [datasheet of the YJL3400A](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1341972/YangzhouYangjie/YJL3400A/1).

It states: *Zero gate voltage drain current* = 1 uA max

So if it was 1 uA through 470 kohm you'd get 470 mV, so 0.3 V is perfectly feasible.

I suggest replacing Q35 with an NMOS that has a lower leakage current!

That YJL3400A has a very low \$R_{DS,on}\$ which is nice if you want to switch large currents but often means such a MOSFET has a relatively high leakage current. Here you don't need that low \$R_{DS,on}\$ so you can use a MOSFET designed for small currents but a low leakage current.

Comment: He says the gate voltage is -0.3. This should cause some head-scratching.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I interpreted that as "correct" (i.e., not wrong) since we're talking about a PMOS where Vgs needs to be negative (Vgate < Vsource) to make it conduct. In some datasheets you also see that a PMOS's threshold voltage has a negative value. Now I see there were oscillations, hmm, weird!

Comment: Thanks again guys for the help.
It definitely seemed strange to me as well!
The oscillations are assumed - I never had an oscilloscope on it, just a voltmeter.  but I assume they have to be pulses of higher negative Vgs in order to turn on the p-mosfet momentarily and let an inrush spike through...
But it could also be that it's actually 2 separate issues.  both solved with the smaller resistor...

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the liberty or re-drawing your circuit and simplifying it to make it easier to spot what may be wrong with it (I've ignored the diodes).[image]

Here are the likely causes of your problem:

1. M1 leaks and creates a voltage drop on the resistor connected to M0 making it turn weakly on.
2. You capacitors are so large that after you turn off the "Power On" there's plenty of charge to keep M1 biased.
3. The most likely: A combination of 1,2 and even a 3rd. You turn off "Power On" but there's enough residual charge on the cap that it biases M1 weakly. This creates current to flow on the resistor of M0 providing a weak bias to M0. This makes more prominent leakage on M0 to Vcc and the cycle repeats. Oh the power of feedback! :D

If you want to further understand the effect of the leakage on the capacitor through M0 this video definitely illustrates the point.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aaxMzw0TqA

(Disclosure: That video is on my YouTube channel.)

This is not the solution you're looking for, it's just broken. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The really confusing part was that I was still getting the Vgs voltage drop even when everything else was removed.  i.e. leaving just the input voltage Vbatt, the resistor across G-S, and the p mosfet…

I finally fixed it.  I don’t know if I fully understand why, but I think when the resistor across G-S gets very large, the own internal capacitance of the mosfet can cause a small current pulse into the resistor and cause a voltage that turns on the mosfet.  I assume with 470k it was oscillating to a steady state Vgs of -.3, and with 100k to a Vgs of -0.05v.  with 24k I couldn’t measure a Vgs, but the output still had .02 and was passing an initial peak that latched Vcc
With 1k everything works perfect!    I will try 5 or 10k tomorrow, just to reduce power loss a bit when on.  But otherwise, I will live with the 1k.

Comment: By lowering the resistor value you're lowering the voltage drop across it. Given what I explained about you're solving the issue. Not optimally though since you're still wasting power due to leakage.